# What causes various signals to be sent?

Tags: process, signals

I sometimes get a little confused by all of the signals that a process can receive. As I understand it, a process has a default handler (*signal disposition*) for each of these signals, but it can provide its own handler by calling [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

So here is my question: what causes each of the signals to be sent? I realize that you can manually send signals to running processes via the `-s` parameter to `kill`, but what are the *natural* circumstances under which these signals are sent? For example, when does `SIGINT` get sent?

Also, are there any restrictions on which signals can be handled? Can even `SIGSEGV` signals be processed and control returned to the application?

Comment: A proper answer to this is going to be epic, and basically replicate the information in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(computing)#List_of_signals) on the matter, so I'll just point there.

Comment: @Shawn: The Wikipedia article has a list of signals, but no clear presentation of who sends what signals.

Comment: See also: [List of Kill Signals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317492/114401)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In addition to processes calling [`kill(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html), some [signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29#List_of_signals) are sent by the kernel (or sometimes by the process itself) in various circumstances:

- Terminal drivers send signals corresponding to various events:

  - Key press notifications:
    [`SIGINT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29) (please go back to the main loop) on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
    [`SIGQUIT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29) (please quit immediately) on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>,
    [`SIGTSTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29) (please suspend) on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. The keys can be changed with the [`stty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/stty.html) command.
  - [`SIGTTIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTTIN) and [`SIGTTOU`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTTOU) are sent when a background process tries to read or write to its controlling terminal.
  - [`SIGWINCH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGWINCH) is sent to signal that the size of the terminal window has changed.
  - [`SIGHUP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) is sent to signal that the terminal has disappeared (historically because your modem had **h**ung **up**, nowadays usually because you've closed the terminal emulator window).
- Some processor traps can generate a signal. The details are architecture and system dependent; here are typical examples:

  - [`SIGBUS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGBUS) for an unaligned access memory;
  - [`SIGSEGV`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) for an access to an unmapped page;
  - [`SIGILL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGILL) for an illegal instruction (bad opcode);
  - [`SIGFPE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGFPE) for a floating-point instruction with bad arguments (e.g. `sqrt(-1)`).
- A number of signals notify the target process that some system event has occured:

  - [`SIGALRM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGALRM) notifies that a timer set by the process has expired. Timers can be set with [`alarm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/alarm.html), [`setitimer`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setitimer.html) and others.
  - [`SIGCHLD`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD) notifies a process that one of its children has died.
  - [`SIGPIPE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE) is generated when a process tries to write to a pipe when the reading end has been closed (the idea is that if you run `foo | bar` and `bar` exits, `foo` gets killed by a `SIGPIPE`).
  - [`SIGPOLL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPOLL) (also called `SIGIO`) notifies the process that a pollable event has occured. POSIX specifies pollable events registered through the `I_SETSIG` [`ioctl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ioctl.html). Many systems allow pollable events on any file descriptor, set via the `O_ASYNC` [`fcntl`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fcntl&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html) flag. A related signal is [`SIGURG`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGURG), which notifies of urgent data on a device (registered via the `I_SETSIG` [`ioctl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ioctl.html)) or [socket](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_10.html#tag_02_10_12).
  - On some systems, [`SIGPWR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPWR) is sent to all processes when the [UPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) signals that a power failure is imminent.

These lists are not exhaustive. Standard signals are defined in [`signal.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html).

Most signals can be caught and handled (or ignored) by the application. The only two portable signals that cannot be caught are [`SIGKILL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL) (just die) and [`STOP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSTOP) (stop execution).

[`SIGSEGV`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) ([segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)) and its cousin [`SIGBUS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGBUS) ([bus error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error)) can be caught, but it's a bad idea unless you really know what you're doing. A common application for catching them is printing a stack trace or other debug information. A more advanced application is to implement some kind of in-process memory management, or to trap bad instructions in virtual machine engines.

Finally, let me mention something that isn't a signal. When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the beginning of a line in a program that's reading input from the terminal, this tells the program that the end of the input file is reached. This isn't a signal: it's transmitted via the input/output API. Like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and friends, the key can be configured with `stty`.

Comment: And SIGHUP, your modem has hung up. :-)

Comment: Another thing to note: `SIGFPE`, somewhat unintuitively, is also signaled on **integer** divide-by-zero, and sometimes on signed integer overflow.

Comment: @ephemient does not happen on Ubuntu 18.04 with bash/dash, when I execute `echo $((1/0))`.

Comment: @jarno It's raised by the kernel if a process attempts it. Most higher-level languages, including shells, check before dividing.

Comment: As for SIGPOLL, I tried killing by that signal in Dash and Bash, but it gave 'kill: SIGPOLL: invalid signal specification' or similar error message.

Comment: "SIGPOLL
This is a System V signal name, more or less similar to SIGIO. It is defined only for compatibility." [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Asynchronous-I_002fO-Signals.html#Asynchronous-I_002fO-Signals)

Comment: On BSD systems, `SIGINFO` is raised when an Ctrl-T is pressed on an interactive terminal.

Answer (score 22):

To answer your second question first: `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL` cannot be caught by the application, but every other signal can, even `SIGSEGV`.  This property is useful for debugging -- for instance, with the right library support, you could listen for `SIGSEGV` and generate a stack backtrace to show just where that segfault happened.

The official word (for Linux, anyway) on what each signal does is available by typing `man 7 signal` from a Linux command line.  http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal has the same information, but the tables are harder to read.

However, without some experience with signals, it's hard to know from the short descriptions what they do in practice, so here's my interpretation:

#### Triggered from the keyboard

- `SIGINT` happens when you hit `CTRL+C`.
- `SIGQUIT` is triggered by `CTRL+\`, and dumps core.
- `SIGTSTP` suspends your program when you hit `CTRL+Z`.  Unlike `SIGSTOP`, it is catchable, which gives programs like `vi` a chance to reset the terminal to a safe state before suspending themselves.

#### Terminal interactions

- `SIGHUP` ("hangup") is what happens when you close your xterm (or otherwise disconnect the terminal) while your program is running.
- `SIGTTIN` and `SIGTTOU` pause your program if it tries to read from or write to the terminal while it's running in the background.  For `SIGTTOU` to happen, I think the program needs to be writing to `/dev/tty`, not just default stdout.

#### Triggered by a CPU exception

These mean your program tried to do something wrong.

- `SIGILL` means an illegal or unknown processor instruction.  This might happen if you tried to access processor I/O ports directly, for example.
- `SIGFPE` means there was a hardware math error; most likely the program tried to divide by zero.
- `SIGSEGV` means your program tried to access an unmapped region of memory.
- `SIGBUS` means the program accessed memory incorrectly in some other way; I won't go into details for this summary.

#### Process interaction

- `SIGPIPE` happens if you try to write to a pipe after the pipe's reader closed their end.  See `man 7 pipe`.
- `SIGCHLD` happens when a child process you created either quits or is suspended (by `SIGSTOP` or similar).

#### Useful for self-signaling

- `SIGABRT` is usually caused by the program calling the `abort()` function, and causes a core dump by default.  Sort of a "panic button".
- `SIGALRM` is caused by the `alarm()` system call, which will cause the kernel to deliver a `SIGALRM` to the program after a specified number of seconds.  See `man 2 alarm` and `man 2 sleep`.
- `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` are used however the program likes.  They could be useful for signaling between processes.

#### Sent by the administrator

These signals are usually sent from the command prompt, via the `kill` command, or `fg` or `bg` in the case of `SIGCONT`.

- `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` are the unblockable signals.  The first always terminates the process immediately; the second suspends the process.
- `SIGCONT` resumes a suspended process.
- `SIGTERM` is a catchable version of `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Which signal is sent when the `shutdown` command is used?

Comment: That depends on the shutdown scripts.  Typically, `SIGTERM` is sent first, followed by a delay, followed by  `SIGKILL`.  In principle, for a hard, immediate shutdown, the kernel doesn't need to send a signal at all; it could just stop running the process.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a supplement or addition to other answers already given, including these:*

1. [List of Kill Signals [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317496/114401)_
2. [What causes various signals to be sent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6337/114401)

**For an even more-detailed explanation of most of these signals, see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)**

One of the most-common signals is the `SIGINT` (or just `INT`) program interrupt signal sent by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> while a process is running.

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) above:

> **`SIGINT`**
>
> *"Signal interrupt"*
> The `SIGINT` signal is sent to a process by its controlling terminal when a user wishes to interrupt the process. This is typically initiated by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but on some systems, the "delete" character or <kbd>"break"</kbd> key can be used.[12]

### How to manually send any signal to any running process

> What causes various signals to be sent [to a running process]?

In addition to other programs or keystrokes causing signals to be sent, **you do!**

Run `kill -l` or `kill --list` to **list all signals you can send to a running process**.

Example run and output:

```bsh
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGUSR2     13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD     18) SIGCONT     19) SIGSTOP     20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGURG      24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO       30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS      34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

So, to send the "alarm" signal (as `SIGALRM`, `ALRM`, or signal number `14`), for example, you can do any one of the following:

```bsh
kill -SIGALRM <pid>
kill -ALRM <pid>
kill -14 <pid>
```

Example `kill` commands to send the alarm signal to pid `123456`:

```bsh
kill -SIGALRM 123456
kill -ALRM 123456
kill -14 123456
```

Read this from `man kill` (emphasis added):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The  default  signal  for  `kill`  is `TERM`.  Use `-l` or `-L` to list available signals.  Particularly useful signals include `HUP`, `INT`, `KILL`, `STOP`, `CONT`, and `0`.  **Alternate signals may be specified in three ways: `-9`, `-SIGKILL` or `-KILL`.**  Negative PID values may be used to choose whole process groups; see the PGID column in `ps` command output.  A PID of `-1` is special; it indicates all processes except the kill process itself and init.

To **find any process ID (pid) of interest**, run this:

```bsh
ps aux | grep "some program name string or regular expression to search for"
```

Look for the signal number in the far left of the output row. The 2nd column from the left is the PID (Process ID) number.

### How to trap any signal in your program

#### 1. In Bash

To "trap", or catch and act on a signal in a custom **bash** program you can do the following (this traps the `SIGALRM` signal):

```bsh
trap <any_comand_to_run_when_signal_is_received> SIGALRM
```

Here is a common trap I use to capture the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> "interrupt" (`SIGINT`, `INT`, or signal number `2`) signal in my custom bash programs:

```bsh
# Trap the Ctrl + C SIGINT signal from this point onward in the bash program so
# that whenever the user presses Ctrl + C, this program prints `Ctrl + C` and
# then exits with exit code 2 (change that to any exit code you'd like to
# return when Ctrl + C is pressed!).
trap 'printf "%s\n" " Ctrl + C"; exit 2' SIGINT
```

See: [Server Fault: Bash Loop - How to stop the loop when I press Control-C inside a command?](https://serverfault.com/a/105390/357116).

#### 2. In C and C++

To trap and act on any given signal in C or C++ on Linux you can use `sigaction()` (best) or `signal()` (not as good, but part of the C standard). See my comprehensive answer on that here, with detailed usage examples: [Stack Overflow: What is the difference between sigaction and signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58815445/4561887)

### Examples of sending (via `kill`) and trapping (via `trap`) signals in bash

Search for the `trap` command (which receives and acts on a signal) and `kill` command (which sends a signal to a process) in these programs:

1. See this bash Centipede game:

   1. [Ask Ubuntu: Command-line snake game?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835990/command-line-snake-game/835994#835994)
   2. In my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo here: [centipede_game.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/centipede_game.sh)