# How do I exit or cancel a bad bash command?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, kill

I expect to get some flak for this, but I can't find the answer anywhere. It seems like it should be so obvious. Sometimes, when I type a bad command in a bash terminal, the cursor just jumps down to the next line without any error or anything. I can't tell what I did wrong. It's like I'm stuck in the program. Reenactment:

```
$ tidy
```

Me: "Oops! That's not what I meant to type..."

```
:q
```

Me: "That didn't work..."

```
:exit
:quit
exit
quit
/exit
/quit
-exit
-quit
-wtf???
```

I know I screwed up but how do I get back to the prompt without closing the terminal?

Comment: Related: [What causes various signals to be sent?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6332)

Comment: `:q` actually worked for me; isn't that a Vim command?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can always try the obvious things like `^C`, `^D` (eof), Escape etc., but if all fails I usually end up suspending the command with `^Z` (Control-Z) which puts me back into the shell.

I then do a `ps` command and note the PID (process id) of the command and then issue a `kill thePID` (`kill -9 thePID` if the former didn't work) command to terminate the application.

Note that this is not a *tidy* (no pun intended) way to terminate the application/command and you run the risk of perhaps no saving some data etc.

An example (I'd have used `tidy` but I don't have it installed):

```
$ gnuplot

    G N U P L O T
    Version 4.2 patchlevel 6 
     ....
    Send bug reports and suggestions to <http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot>

Terminal type set to 'wxt'
gnuplot> 
gnuplot>               #####  typed ^Z here
[1]+  Stopped                 gnuplot
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1681 pts/1    00:00:00 tcsh
 1690 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 1708 pts/1    00:00:00 gnuplot
 1709 pts/1    00:00:00 ps


$ kill 1708            ###### didn't kill the command as ps shows

$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1681 pts/1    00:00:00 tcsh
 1690 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 1708 pts/1    00:00:00 gnuplot
 1710 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
$ kill -9 1708           ### -9 did the trick
$ 
[1]+  Killed                  gnuplot

$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1681 pts/1    00:00:00 tcsh
 1690 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 1711 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: That's it!! ^Z to the rescue. Thank you so much.

Comment: @davidkennedy85 Happy to help ... I was just cobbling together an example to post

Comment: ^\ (ctrl-backslash, SIGQUIT) works in some stubborn utilities that don't respond to ^C.

Comment: Shh! Don't tell people about the ^\ or they'll start `SIG_IGN`'ing that too, then what will we do?

Comment: I'd recommend ^Z, then kill %% to kill the job nicely, then kill -9 %% to kill it harshly if necessary.  And using %% instead of using ps to find a pid is much easier.

Comment: @godlygeek Can you tell me what %% means in Linux or what kind of thing it is? I searched a lot.

Comment: @Noumenon, have a look at `LESS='+/^JOB CONTROL' man bash`.  `%%` refers to the "current job".

Comment: `kill -KILL <pid>` or `kill -SIGKILL <pid>` is more readable than `kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: What is the ^ key?

Comment: @marsh ^ is for control key, so ^Z would be Control-Z, ^C -> Control-C, etc .. ^Z suspends a command, ^C kills/terminates it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 16):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. If it fails, kill the process .

Trying with the `tidy` command you mentioned, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> works.

Comment: `CTRL+C` is good for windows CMD too.

Answer (score 12):

Another solution (not mentioned already) is to send the `SIGQUIT` signal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

It is *stronger* than a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> `==  exit shell command`

and

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> `== terminate the current process, Of course may be the given software handle it and` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> `doens't work`

Of course , They produce a `kernel signal` if you want to know more, read :

```
man 7 signal
```

Comment: Ctrl+D is end-of-file, not directly exit.