# What is the difference between exiting a process via Ctrl+C vs issuing a kill -9 command?

Tags: process, kill, command, signals, process-management

I know I can kill any process with kill -9 command . But sometimes i see that even if I have terminated a program with <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> , the process doesn't get killed . So I want to know the difference between kill -9 vs <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>

Comment: See also [What causes various signals to be sent?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6332/6337#6337)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`^C` send the interrupt signal, which can be handled by a program (you can ignore it)

`kill -9` send the sigkill signal which kills the program that you can't handle.

That's why you can't kill some programs with ^C

Comment: One critical difference is that "well behaved" programs will catch ctrl-C and clean up after themselves (detach from any shared resources, destroy temporary files, reset the terminal to a sane state), SIGKILL doesn't give them that chance. BTW, it can happen that a program is stuck in an unkillable state inside the kernel.

Comment: @l0b0: `^C` sends `SIGINT`. `kill` (without `-9`) sends `SIGTERM`. Both those work the same, and can be handled by the program, but they're independent signals.

Comment: If `^C` doesn't work then you should try `kill` next, and then only `kill -9` if you have to. The difference is that `kill` on it's own gives the program chance to clean up its files and whatnot. `kill -9` just removes it without asking nicely.

Comment: Aka. `SIGINT` (thanks @ams) and `SIGKILL`