# Stop multiple processes from command line correctly

Tags: kill, ps

I'm executing the following command on mac

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch & nodemon dist/server.js
```

I tried killing the processes using Ctrl+C however i still notice that node processes are running (when i do a ps). Is there anyway to kill the processes correctly i this case?

Comment: You can try to kill the process politely with `kill PID` (SIGTERM). If it doesn't work, kill it effectively with `kill -9 PID` (SIGKILL). See [What is the difference between exiting a process via Ctrl+C vs issuing a kill -9 command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62258/what-is-the-difference-between-exiting-a-process-via-ctrlc-vs-issuing-a-kill-9)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@nev.m,

you can run this command,

> ps aux | grep 'process name' | xargs kill -9

it will list all the process by process name then kill it.

Comment: While this often works in practice, it is a bad idea. Assume you have an unrelated process that has 'process name' as part of its arguments. Then you risk killing that, too. So never do this on a production system.

Comment: Thanks @OleTange . yup, this is more for just a dev environment.