# Decode Flags for Kill Command

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, kill, signals

I saw this Command on a Book for Linux shell Scripting

```
$ kill -HUP 1234 >killout.txt 2>killerr.txt
```

I know what the command does, but i am not able to understand the flags **-HUP**

Comment: `man kill; apropos signal`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Linux try `man 7 signal`.

`kill -HUP 1234` means "send the SIGHUP signal (1) to process 1234", so it's equivalent to `kill -1 1234`. The default signal that is sent by kill is SIGTERM (15), so `kill 1234` is equivalent to `kill -TERM 1234` or `kill -15 1234`.

Comment: Note that the POSIX syntax is `kill -s HUP`. `kill -HUP` and `kill -1` are Unix (XSI extension in the SUS) but not POSIX. Note that `kill -s HUP` and `kill -1` are the same as per Unix, but the signal **number** for `HUP` is not guaranteed to be `1` (in case you expect a process killed with `HUP` to return an exit status of 129 or 257)

Answer (score 4):

`-HUP` isn't the three flags `H`, `U`, `P` as in the common single-letter option syntax. For historical reasons, the `kill` command takes an optional signal name or signal number preceded by a dash (`-`).

```
kill -1 1234
kill -HUP 1234
```

(As opposed to `kill 1 1234`, which would send the default signal (SIGTERM) to processes 1 and 1234.)

Your man page probably lists something like this:

```
kill [ -signal | -s signal ] pid ...
```

That `-signal` means that you can use a dash followed by a signal designation (which can be a name or number). Alternatively, you can use the `-s` option followed by a signal name; these are two different syntaxes with the same meaning.

`kill -l` lists the available signal names and the corresponding numbers.

Most [signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) have a predefined meaning based on [who sends them when](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6332/what-causes-various-signals-to-be-sent/6337#6337) and how processes are supposed and able to react to them.