# Does SIGHUP get triggered upon broken telnet/SSH connection?

Tags: networking, signals

I'm trying to write a mail program which might contain data that a user wouldn't want to lose upon a broken SSH/telnet connection. Would `SIGHUP` be sent to the process? After all, it's the "hangup" signal...

Comment: It depends - see for example [In which cases is SIGHUP not sent to a job when you log out?](84737).

Comment: @Thomas, ITYM [In which cases is SIGHUP not sent to a job when you log out?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84737). (yes, I agree it's a real pain to link to other questions in comments).

Comment: Depends if a pty is used. So with telnet yes, with ssh, only for interactive sessions or if passed -t/-tt

Comment: odd - it looked okay after I saved the edit.

Comment: @Thomas, just found [SE Comment Link Helper](https://stackapps.com/q/2378), testing just now (edit: it works!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the process will be sent a `SIGHUP`.  The default signal handler (trap) will shutdown the program relatively gracefully, but won't save the users work.

In your case, I would have the program include a trap routine that saves the user's work when a `SIGHUP` is received.  You can catch and handle all signals except `SIGKILL`.  You may also want to run the same routine for a `SIGTERM` interupt.

There are other mechanisms that can be used to avoid getting a `SIGHUP` signal, but handling the signal is the simplest and safest.  If the other approachs fail, or a `SIGHUP` is sent with the `kill` command your process would still shutdown without saving the work.

Comment: With `ssh host 'cmd'`, `cmd` won't get a SIGHUP if the connection drops. `cmd` could get a SIGPIPE if it  tries to write something on stdout/stderr after the connection has dropped (with openssh, there are issues with that when using connection sharing).