# Is it the process that has a controlling terminal, or is it the session that has a controlling terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

When we say that a process has a controlling terminal, do we mean that the process itself has a controlling terminal, or is it the session that the process belongs to that has a controlling terminal?

I used to think that it is the session that has a controlling terminal, but then I have read the following (from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Terminal.html)) which implies that it is the process that has a controlling terminal:

> One of the attributes of a process is its controlling terminal. Child
>   processes created with fork inherit the controlling terminal from
>   their parent process. In this way, all the processes in a session
>   inherit the controlling terminal from the session leader. A session
>   leader that has control of a terminal is called the controlling
>   process of that terminal.

Comment: Read [The tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page.

Comment: Bam.... see if this helps clarify any too.... http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~ivana/courses/ps/sistemi_knjige/pomocno/apue/APUE/0201433079/ch09lev1sec6.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## It is indeed the session that has a controlling terminal

The *Single UNIX Specification* describes the relationship in terms of the *controlling terminal* being "associated with a session".  As it goes on to specify, a controlling terminal has a 1:1 relationship with a session.  There is "at most one controlling terminal" associated with a session, and "a controlling terminal is associated with exactly one session".

The FreeBSD *Design and Implementation* book approaches this slightly differently, but reaches the same place.  It is not possible for processes that share the same session to have different controlling terminals, nor is it possible for a single terminal to be the controlling terminal of multiple sessions.

Internally in FreeBSD that is how the data structures actually work.  The process structure has a pointer to the `pgrp` structure representing the process group that the process belongs to, which in turn points to the `session` structure representing the session that the process group belongs to, which in turn points to the `tty` structure of the controlling terminal for the session.

Internally in Linux, things are slightly more complex.  Each `task_struct` has a set of pointers to `pid` structures for its process group ID and session ID; and has another pointer to a per-process `signal_struct` structure that in turn directly points to the `tty` structure of the controlling terminal.

## Further reading

- George V. Neville-Neil, Marshall Kirk McKusick, and Robert N.M. Watson (2014-09-25). "Process Management". *The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System*.  Addison-Wesley Professional.  ISBN 9780133761832.
- Donald Lewine (1991).  "Terminal I/O".  *POSIX Programmers Guide*.  O'Reilly Media, Inc.  ISBN 9780937175736.
- Daniel P. Bovet and Marco Cesati (2005).  "Processes".  *Understanding the Linux Kernel: From I/O Ports to Process Management*. 3rd edition. O'Reilly Media, Inc. ISBN 9780596554910.
- "Definitions".  *The Open Group Base Specifications*.  Issue 7.  2016. IEEE 1003.1:2008.
- "General Terminal Interface".  *The Open Group Base Specifications*.  Issue 7.  2016. IEEE 1003.1:2008.

Comment: So, does Linux kernel satisfy this relationship? I mean, is that possible in Linux to make processes in the same session use different controlling terminals or let one terminal be multi sessions' controlling terminal?

Comment: Thanks. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492756/is-controlling-terminal-a-per-process-concept

Answer (score -1):

<sub><sup>my knowledge is not sufficient, following answer can be wrong</sup></sub>

#### @key::

> **any process can detach from its controlling tty, if it has one, with the `TIOCNOTTY ioctl`.**
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649796/how-would-the-existing-processes-in-the-session-learn-about-and-acquire-the-cont
>
> existing children are not affected.
>
> [When a session leader acquires a controlling terminal, how would the other existing processes in the session also acquire the controlling terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446738/when-a-session-leader-acquires-a-controlling-terminal-how-would-the-other-exist/446740)

#### => (@answer::)

- in a large scope, the `session_SS` (as a whole of many process) & the `controlling_terminal_FF` can be **associated** or not
- (say now, `session_SS` is associated with the `controlling_terminal_FF`)

  for each individual processes (inside `session_SS`),

  **they are still not necessarily be associated with the `controlling_terminal_FF`** (ie: detached, have no controlling terminal)

  (they have the option of being associated with the `controlling_terminal_FF` or not)

  - but the option is **constrained** to only one terminal -- the `controlling_terminal_FF`.
- [[so, there isnt really any strict "have/contain" relation how you commonly call it,

  its about the "association/rules/constraints",

  the session can "have/associate" & the process can also "have/associate" with the terminal -- the session "constrains" how the process can associate]]

#### @details::

say you have created a lot of processes, process groups, sessions.

now you have a process `session_leader_AA` in `session_SS`

you have a `terminal_FF`

when a `session_leader_AA` in `session_SS` **connects/open() a `terminal_FF`** -- that `terminal_FF` becomes the controlling terminal of `session_SS` (and `session_leader_AA` becomes the controlling process of `terminal_FF`)

- a child process **inherits** the controlling terminal from its parent process

  - any child process in `session_SS` that **already existed** before `session_leader_AA` connects to a `terminal_FF`

    -- are still not connected with any terminal
  - any child process in `session_SS` that are created after `session_leader_AA` connects to a `terminal_FF`, but **not child processes** of `session_leader_AA`

    -- are still not connected with any terminal
- **any process can detach from its controlling tty, if it has one, with the `TIOCNOTTY ioctl`.**

#### @rule,note::

- 1 controlling terminal can only connect with 1 session

  1 session can only connect with 1 controlling terminal
- **All of the processes in a session can have a (single) controlling terminal**

  ie: processes have a controlling terminal, (some processes have no controlling terminal,) and that controlling terminal they have, must be referring to the same one.
- The `ioctl(fd, TIOCNOTTY)` operation can be used to remove a process’s association with its controlling terminal.

  (any process can call `ioctl(fd, TIOCNOTTY)`, if that process has an associated controlling terminal)

  (Especially,) If the controlling process `session_leader_AA` for the `controlling_terminal_FF` calls `ioctl(fd, TIOCNOTTY)`

  the following steps occur:

  1. All processes in the session lose their association with the controlling terminal.
  2. The controlling terminal loses its association with the session,

     (and can therefore be acquired as the controlling terminal +- by another session leader.)
  3. The kernel sends a SIGHUP signal (and a SIGCONT signal)

     +- to all members of the foreground process group,

     +- to inform them of the loss of the controlling terminal.

  - (these are the same steps occur when the controlling process terminates)

  > The Linux Programming Interface
- <sub>there are other associated pbs, no confirmation on the answer yet:_

  1. so call non-controlling terminal:_ regular terminal as file / terminal connected but non-controlling, only for reading data
  2. does the detached process not receving inputs from the Controlling_Terminal (purpose)
  3. > 1. a `session_leader_AA` in `session_SS` **connects/open() a `terminal_FF`** -- that `terminal_FF` becomes the controlling terminal of `session_SS`
     > 2. a child process **inherits** the controlling terminal from its parent process

     seems the only 2 way to associate a (session/)process with a terminal
  4. seems even process in Foreground_Process_Group can be detached from the Controlling_Terminal</sub>

Comment: This answer is difficult to read due to its unorthodox use of headers and markup in general.