# How to create device files manually use mknod?

Tags: linux-kernel, devices, embedded, block-device

Linux 2.6.26.5 embedded. I need manually mount the root file system from busybox shell (initramfs). Because this Linux kernel not use devtmpfs, I have to create the basic device nodes manually, use mknod (`/dev/null`, `/dev/zero`, `dev/mtdblock` {0-10}, `ttys`). I'm not sure about correct format for `/dev/mtdblock` and `ttys`. Should I create nodes for both /dev/mtdblock and /dev/mtd? The device creates 11 MTD partitions on nand0.
Where to find the major and minor numbers assigned for a devices?
The same question for ttys: what is correct mknod command for  `5 /dev/tty` and  `4 tty` - are they in different places?

```
mknod -m 666 tty c 4 0
mknod -m 666 /dev/tty c 5 0
```

Edit: partitions, devices and filesystems

```
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

  31     0        384 mtdblock0
  31     1        128 mtdblock1
  31     2      20352 mtdblock2
  31     3       7168 mtdblock3
  31     4      18816 mtdblock4
  31     5       2048 mtdblock5
  31     6       1024 mtdblock6
  31     7        512 mtdblock7
  31     8        128 mtdblock8
  31     9        512 mtdblock9
  31    10        512 mtdblock10
# cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
  1 mem
  2 pty
  3 ttyp
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  7 vcs
 10 misc
 13 input
 89 i2c
 90 mtd
108 ppp
128 ptm
136 pts
153 spi
204 ttyJ
254 cordless

Block devices:
  1 ramdisk
 31 mtdblock
 93 nftl
```

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question open as questions about *official documentation* are explicitly *on-topic*.

Comment: `mknod /dev/mtdblock0 b 31 0` will create the mtdblock0 for you. Tricky question: what do you think, what could mean the "major" and "minor" columns in `/proc/partitions`? :-)

Comment: @peterh yes, I know that the "major" and "minor" numbers is specified in columns in /proc/partitions. What's not clear: I have 11 partitions, but I want access only root (mtd4), so  would be the _mtd4/mtdblock4 device node pair_ sufficient here? Or I have to create all device nodes mtdx and mtdblockx **for each partition**?(even if I want accees only root)

Comment: @triwo Then ask this in a new question. You've got your answer for your problem, now you can have your next question.

Answer (score 3):

Device files are essentially a table in the kernel. A C array.

More exactly, a two-level tree structure of C arrays: the upper level for the major numbers and the lower for the minors.

Drivers (and the kernel core), can register driver handlers for them. A driver uses always a major number. For example, the software raid ("md") users the block major 9.

You can get the list of the currently registered block- and char devices in the `/proc/devices` files.

The final answer is in the kernel source, there are "(un)register_block_device" or similar calls of the kernel core. Find them, `grep` for them, and so you can get a full list.

Comment: Should be created nodes for both mtdblockX and mtdX devices? Also, not clear about TTY devices.

Comment: @triwo `tty` is only a character device, in its functionality is it essentially a socket, extended with some terminal-controlling ioctl()-s. There is a "tty driver" in the kernel, it registers the ttys with a `register_char_device(4)` (or similar, check the source) call. From that point, the open/close/read/write/ioctl and similar calls to character device files with major number 4 will be implemented by the `tty` driver. The `tty` driver handles the character console of the Linux kernel. There is also a `pts` driver, its major number is 136, it is mainly for the daemons, like sshd.

Comment: @triwo From the ttys I wrote more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386957/52236). | mtd & mtdblock: I don't know the details. But: It is quite possible that a driver registers multiple block major numbers. Typically they mean different functionality: for example, in kernels until ca. 2.2, `/dev/sr0` (block major 11) meaned an scsi cdrom, while `/dev/sg0`(block major 21) was a generic scsi device. The scsi cdrom driver used both. I think some similar could happen also in the mtd / mtdblock line.

Comment: @triwo The kernel core doesn't know anything about the path/filename of the device files, it see only block/char and major/minor numbers. The device files below `/dev` are normally created by the userspace tool named `udev`, but from the view of the kernel, it is not a requirement. The kernel can see a table of major numbers and that which driver belongs to them.

Comment: I added mtd & mtdblock commands to the topic. Which version for mtd chars should I use?

Comment: @triwo Maybe you could check it in `/proc/devices`?

Comment: Edit: I added devices and partitions scheme. What is correct **mknod** command syntax to create mtd, mtdblock, ttys device files for my specific case?

Comment: @triwo `mknod b 1 2`, where "1" and "2" are the major and minor numbers of the required device. If it is a character device, then `mknod c 1 2`. I've just explained, where can you find the installed devices.

Comment: @triwo Sorry, the correct command is: `mknod devicename b 1 2`.

Comment: I think this will not work.

Comment: @triwo I think you should try it, and if it doesn't work, then ask it as a new question, instead of requiring free support in comment chats.

Comment: @triwo Then topic closed.

Answer (score 1):

From [devices.txt in the kernel documentation](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/devices.txt).